# How to remove menu option when right clicking on DevExpress Xtra GridControl Column Header?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Any body please help me how to do remove menu option when right clicking on DevExpress Xtra Grid Control Column header

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it with the following property:

```
GridOptionsMenu.EnableColumnMenu
```

Which is on the Gridview.

Comment: This works, but to get the most control you should handle the event as described in the below answer.

Comment: I can't see any reason not to use the given property to hide the entire menu at once, rather than handling the event.  Certainly the event gives you more control, but that assumes you actually need all that control.

Comment: I meant if you only need to remove certain properties :P

Comment: Well, yeah the property would definitely not be useful in that case.

Answer (score -1):

this.gridView.OptionsMenu.EnableColumnMenu = false;

Comment: This seems like a minor change on the existing answer. Please [edit] to make more obvious what additional insight you contribute. Why/when is this alternative needed? How does it work? Why does it help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).